# Why does the btrfs-subvolume list command list all subvolumes?

Tags: mount, btrfs

Experimenting with BTRFS in a VM environment.

I have created 2 sub-volumes (flat structure)

```
ID 256 gen 13 top level 5 path @
ID 256 gen 9 top level 5 path @home
```

I have mounted the `@` and `@home` under `/mnt & /mnt/home` respectively, like so:

```
mount -o noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd,subvol=@ /dev/vda3 /mnt
mount -o noatime,space_cache=v2,compress=zstd,subvol=@home /dev/vda3 /mnt/home
```

When I get the list of sub-volumes under `/mnt/home` I see both sub-volumes

```
btrfs subvolume list /mnt/home
ID 256 gen 13 top level 5 path @
ID 256 gen 9 top level 5 path @home
```

Is this the expected behavior?  I would have expected to see only `@home`

Am I doing something wrong (maybe not creating the sub-volumes correctly or not mounting them correctly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. From the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/btrfs-subvolume.8.html):

> List the subvolumes present in the filesystem `<path>`.

So by default the given path is merely there to identify the filesystem to inspect.

To get more what you expected you can use the option `-o`.

> print only subvolumes below specified `<path>`.

But note that this option prints only subvolumes *below* the given path and again path is merely an identifier for the subvolume to start from.

For example I have a root (/) subvolume, a separate /usr subvolume and snapshot volume outside the normal root.

```
$ btrfs subvolume list -ta /
ID      gen     top level       path
--      ---     ---------       ----
256     564502  5               <FS_TREE>/@rootfs
265     564432  256             @rootfs/usr
277     564433  5               <FS_TREE>/@snapshots
```

If I add the `-o` flag

```
$ btrfs subvolume list -o /
ID 265 gen 564432 top level 256 path @rootfs/usr
```

I only get the `usr` subvolume because it is below root. The root subvolume (ID 256) is out because it is the subvolume identified by path `/` and therefore not below and snapshot (ID 277) is removed because it is a sibling to `@rootfs`.

To make things a bit confusing again, something like

```
$ btrfs subvolume list -o /var
ID 265 gen 564432 top level 256 path @rootfs/usr
```

produces the same result even if /usr is not below /var but /var is a path in the @rootfs subvolume.

Comment: That explains what I am seeing - but as you pointed out that is confusing :-)